# Deserailize JSON string

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have JSON in this format:

```
{
 "user": "123@abc",
 "filter": [
 {
"filterName": "Filter1",
"condition": "1",
"values": [
"123"
 ]
},
{
"filterName": "Filter2",
"condition": "2",
"values": [
"ABC",
"XYZ"
]
}
],
"onlyMerge": "true",
"mergeBy": [ 
  ]
 }
```

And I am using these classes

```
 public class Outermost{
 public string user;
 public Root filter ;
 public string onlyMerge;
 public string mergeby;
}

 public class values {
     public string value { get; set; } 
 }

 public class Filters {
     public string filtername {get; set; }
     public string condition {get; set;}
     public values values { get; set; }
 }
 public class Root {
     public List<Filters> Filters { get; set; }
 }
```

JSONConvert.Deserialize(Outermost)
I have to deserialize the structure

Answer (score 2):

Paste your JSON into http://json2csharp.com/ and you will see that your C# classes don't match the JSON.

Comment: Ow, You were faster than me... :)

Comment: Thanks ! :) prob Resolved

Answer (score 2):

**Update 2:**

Visual Studio 2013 has a built-in Json to C# Class converter tool!  :)

**Update:**

Just a note about the great tool http://json2csharp.com/ : When working with a object that has properties of complex types, You may want to check about the classes it creates, because sometimes it'll created unnecessarily/undesirable classes. Example:

**Json**

```
var objJson = {
    "id_product": 19,
    "description": "Laptop",
    "_links": {
        "buy": {
            "href": "/Product/Buy/19",
            "title": "Buy It Now!"
        },
        "more_details": {
            "href": "/Product/Details/19",
            "title": "More Details..."
        }
    }
};
```

**Generated Class/Classes:**

```
public class Buy
{
    public string href { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
}
public class MoreDetails
{
    public string href { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
}
public class Links
{
    public Buy buy { get; set; }
    public MoreDetails more_details { get; set; }
}
public class RootObject
{
    public int id_product { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public Links _links { get; set; }
}
```

As You can see, the two classes `Buy` and `MoreDetails` have exactly the same structure and purpose, so You **may** want to replace it with a more generic class instead of using repeatedly classes (there are scenarios where this redundant structure is more appropriate). In a very similar scenario, I've created a class named `Link`.

**Original Answer:**

You don't said enough to be sure what's your problem. Try in the future specify better what are your difficulties and needs.

But, I guess your problem is some exception being throw or some properties not being bind...

If you pay attention, in your JSON example object, filter is directly a collection, and not a property that has a collection inside. Thus, just change 

`public Root filter;` to `public List<Filters> filter { get; set; }`.
Also, `mergeBy` and `values` are collections, and not simple strings. You could use http://json2csharp.com/ to generate automatically the correspondent C# class of your JSON object, and check what properties are not matching... (Or, substitute your whole class, that is what I would recommend...)